# Representing homotopy as a continuous path in non-locally compact spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let us consider three topological spaces $X, Y, Z$. It is well known that a sufficient condition to establish the equivalence (homeomorphic spaces) between $C^{0}(Z\times X,Y)$ and $C^{0}\left(Z,C^{0}(X,Y)_{co}\right)$ (where "co" means equipped with the compact-open topology) is that $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact. Therefore, these assumptions do not cover the case where $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space because it lacks local compactness. Does this result remain true in the case of
$$
C^{0}(Z\times H,H)\overset{?}{\simeq}C^{0}\left(Z,C^{0}(H,H)_{co}\right)
$$
where $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space? Should we consider other topologies for $C^{0}(H,H)$?
My question is motivated by the fact that I would like to represent the homotopy $h\in C^{0}(\left[0,1\right]\times H,H)$ in this more general setting as a continuous path in $C^{0}\left(\left[0,1\right],C^{0}(H,H)_{co}\right)$.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are Hausdorff and first-countable, then adjunction gives a natural homeomorphism $C_{ko}(X\times Y,Z)\cong C_{ko}(X,C_{ko}(Y,Z))$ for any space $Z$. In particular this holds when $X,Y$ are metric spaces.

Comment: @Tyrone thank you for your answer. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: The result can be found in Jackson's paper [Spaces of mappings on topological products with applications to homotopy theory](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-02/S0002-9939-1952-0047322-4/). Note that "locally separable" should read "first-countable". It makes use of an older statement due to Fox, which can be found in his paper [On topologies for function spaces](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-06/S0002-9904-1945-08370-0/) (see Theorem 2).